# Cannot modify header information after upgrade to cakephp3.6

Tags: cakephp

After upgrading cakephp3.2 to 3.6 i am getting errors on a live server that i wasnt getting on my local. 
I dont understand what to fix with this error as the code refers to setup code that i dont touch. The docs havent clarified these issues

```
 // this is code that i dont touch so what am i doing to fix this?
   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/andrewto/public_html/crmcta/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:853) 


//i dont understand how to fix this depricated error as just using withType didnt work
Deprecated (16384): Response::type() is deprecated. Use getType() or withType() instead. - /home/andrewto/public_html/crmcta/src/Controller/AppController.php, line: 137
  public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    }
```

http://andrewt.com.au/crmcta/users/login

Comment: Read the error message? It already tells you what you need to do and where the issue is coming from? AppController.php, line: 137

Comment: Most likely withType() doesnt work for you because you didnt respect immutability. So make sure you re-assign your changed response: `$this->response = $this->response->withType()` etc.
This is clearly documented however for newer CakePHP versions.

Comment: I dont understand why my test server on my localhost failed to pick up an error but a copy of the exact same website picks up everything. What setting am i looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that you need to do is to disable deprecation errors on your live server. You can do it by setting `Error.errorLevel` to `E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED` in your config/app.php.

Then you can work on replacing deprecated methods with new ones - in your example you should use `$this->response->getType()` instead of deprecated `$this->response->type()`.

Comment: This is the best a workaround. The deprecated methods should be corrected to whatever their new name is. Cake usually tells you that - if you read bother to read the error message.

Comment: If this is working on the test server but not the live, then maybe deprecation warnings are enabled on the live but not on the test. That's exactly backwards.

Comment: Is deprecation errors causing the header issues which i still get after fixing a few of these issues? I tried getType and this worked.